# how to return result value instead of promise?

Tags: react-native, promise

I'm trying to get the return value from a promise but I couldn't.

I'm importing { sha256 } from 'react-native-sha256'

```
const sha256 = sha256(keytohash);
return sha256;
```

Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null} <<< this is what I get when I console.log

I also tried:

```
const sha256 = async () => {
const key = await sha256(keytohash).then(hash => (hash));
return key;
};

return sha256;
```

Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null} <<< this is what I get when I console.log

Is there anyway to let me get the hash value instead of the promise object?

Comment: `return JSON.stringfly(sha256);` can you try this?

Comment: The way you get a value out of a promise is with `.then()`.  That's it.  You can't ever return a value directly from an async operation.

Comment: @hongdevelop not working, below is the result:

`Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
_40: 0
_55: "{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}"
_65: 1
_72: null
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Try!

```
const getSha256 = async () => {
  const key = await sha256(keytohash)
  return key;
}

console.log(getSha256())
```

You returned async function instead of value.

```
Math.random = function
Math.random() = value
```

You need wait promise.resolve by using await.

Comment: not working, it will still return me promise object

Comment: Have you used debugger?
You can stop code by writing "debbuger" in your code.
try
const getSha256 = async () => {
  const key = await sha256(keytohash)
  debbuger
  return key;
}

Comment: what's the different? the value i got still the promise object